# What is this error? related to SPARQL.

Tags: time, limit, response, sparql, execution

During the construction process of SPARQL, I am having following error. I don't understand whether there is limitation on querying or not?

```
 Response:
 Virtuoso 42000 Error The estimated execution time 253 (sec) exceeds the limit   of 240 (sec).
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This means the data you are getting out takes longer than usual to be processed. If you are using the online endpoint, you can't do anything but setting a `limit` or filtering (`filter`) your data even more. Or you can consider getting a dataset dump and run in on your system.

Comment: Yes, it is possible. Just add another triple such as `?o ?p ?s` to your query. And you are asking questions in the comment of different questions and this is misleading for future reference.